# How to add translucency effect in flutter desktop application (macOS)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a desktop app and would like to add a translucency effect as shown in the image below. Would this be possible in flutter?

[image: Transparency/Vibrancy example]

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a native view behind the Flutter view to achieve that effect; Flutter has no way of accessing the pixel data of the content behind the window in order to apply a filter effect to it.

So you should be able to make a macOS Flutter application with that effect, but you can't do that specific part within Flutter.